# how to solve this spark-scala sql error message

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, connector

To remove duplicate rows, I attempt this sql

```
val characters = MongoSpark.load[sparkSQL.Character](sparkSession)
characters.createOrReplaceTempView("characters")
val testsql = sparkSession.select("SELECT * FROM characters GROUP BY title")
testsql.show()
```

but this sql make this error message.
if you know this problem, please answer this questin.

thanks you

```
Parsing command: SELECT * FROM characters GROUP BY title
Exception in thread "main" org.spache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
expression 'characters.`url`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function
Add to Add to group by  or wrap in first() if you don't care which value you get.;;
```

and then i attempt like this but i don't know this is right solution....

please answer this question. thanks you!

```
val characters = MongoSpark.load[sparkSQL.Character](sparkSession)
characters.createOrReplaceTempView("characters")
val testsql = sparkSession.select("SELECT * FROM characters")
testgrsql = testsql.groupBy("title")
testgrsql.show()
```

Comment: SELECT colums mentioned in GROUPBY `val testsql = sparkSession.sql("SELECT title FROM characters GROUP BY title")`, If you are not using any aggregate functions.

Comment: Hi, if below answer has solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Error message explains everything,

> Parsing command: SELECT * FROM characters GROUP BY title
>
> *Exception in thread "main" org.spache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
>   expression **'characters.url' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function***
>
> Add to Add to group by  or wrap in first() if you don't care which value you get.;;

So the usage can be, If you want first url value for each title then `first(url)`

```
characters.createOrReplaceTempView("characters")
val testsql = sparkSession.sql("SELECT title, first(url) FROM characters GROUP BY title")
```